# How to quote this parameter in perl module

Tags: perl, twitter

I'm trying to use the AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream module and I want to reference a file that lists the Twitter uids I want to follow.  I can put the uids in the code itself and it works as follows:

```
my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;
       my $nt_filter = AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream->new(
             username => $cf{account},
             password => $cf{password},
           method => 'filter',
           follow => '15855509,14760150,18598536',
            on_tweet => sub {
                 #some code.....
            },
            on_error => sub {
                my $error = shift;
                debug "ERROR: $error";
            },
            timeout => 45,
        );
       $done->recv;
```

But when I try to do the same using a file as such:

```
my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;
       my $nt_filter = AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream->new(
           open UID_FILE, "/tmp/uids" or die $!;

           my @uid_line = <UID_FILE>;

             username => $cf{account},
             password => $cf{password},
           method => 'filter',
           follow => @uid_file,
            on_tweet => sub {
                  #some code....
            },
            on_error => sub {
                my $error = shift;
                debug "ERROR: $error";
            },
            timeout => 45,
        );
       $done->recv;
```

it fails.  The uids file has the following contents:

```
'15855509,14760150,18598536'
```

I'm getting a 406 error from Twitter, suggesting the format is not correct.  I'm guessing the quotes are not correct somehow?

Comment: Do you need to chomp the line from UID file to remove a possible lending? I'd compare the actual HTTP requests to see what's going on. Find a tool such as HTTPScoop to record that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream` module subclasses `AnyEvent` and you don't need to access the base module at all. All the functionality is provided by the `new` method and the callbacks that you specify there, and you shouldn't call `AnyEvent->condvar` or `$done->recv`.

The `open` call and assignment to `@uid_line` don't belong inside the call to `AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream->new`.

Furthermore the variable you are using to supply the value for the `follow` parameter is `@uid_file` instead of `@uid_line`.

You *must* `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the start of your programs, especially if you are asking for help with them. This will trap simple mistakes like this that you could otherwise overlook.

You can't in general use an array to supply a single scalar value. In this instance it may be OK as long as the file has only a single line (so there is only one element in the array) but there is a lot that could go wrong.

In addition you are passing single-quotes in the value that don't belong there: they appear in the code only to mark the start and end of the Perl string.

I suggest you read all decimal strings from your file like this

```
open my $uid_fh, '<', '/tmp/uids' or die $!;
my @uids;
push @uids, /\d+/g for <$uid_fh>;
```

(Note that these lines belong *before* the call to `AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream->new`)

Then you can supply the `follow` parameter by writing

```
follow => join(',', @uids),
```

I hope this is clear. Please ask again if you need further help.

---

**Edit**

These changes incorporated into your code should look like this, but it is incomplete and I cannot guarantee that it will work properly.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream;

open my $uid_fh, '<', '/tmp/uids' or die $!;
my @uids;
push @uids, /\d+/g for <$uid_fh>;

my %cf = (
  account => 'myaccount',
  password => 'password',
);

my $nt_filter = AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream->new(
  username => $cf{account},
  password => $cf{password},
  method => 'filter',
  follow => join(',', @uids),
  on_tweet => sub {
    #some code....
  },
  on_error => sub {
    my $error = shift;
    debug "ERROR: $error";
  },
  timeout => 45,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to pass an array in a scalar context so it is possible that you are setting follow to `1`, the number of elements in the array (the number of lines in the file).

Assuming there is only a single line of IDs in your file, does the following work:

```
   open UID_FILE, "/tmp/uids" or die $!;

   # Load the first line of uids
   my $uid_line = <UID_FILE>;

   # Remove apostrophes from input.
   # This may or may not be necessary
   $uid_line =~ s/'//g;

   # Don't forget to close the file
   close(UID_FILE);

   my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;
   my $nt_filter = AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream->new(

         username => $cf{account},
         password => $cf{password},
       method => 'filter',
       follow => $uid_line,
        on_tweet => sub {
              #some code....
        },
        on_error => sub {
            my $error = shift;
            debug "ERROR: $error";
        },
        timeout => 45,
    );
   $done->recv;
```

You will probably need to strip the leading and trailing apostrophes from your input line. For example:

```
$uid_line =~ s/^'//;
$uid_line =~ s/'$//;
```

You could probably get away with just removing all apostrophes, e.g.:

```
$uid_line =~ s/'//g;
```

Comment: I've updated my code to move the open outside the call to AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream->new as @Borodin points out.